# A linear transformation defined by a system of equations carries $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathbb{R}^m$ iff the rank of the coefficient matrix is $m$.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show that a linear transformation defined by a system of equation carries $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathbb{R}^m$ if and only if the rank of the coefficient matrix of the system is $m$.

So I understand that we can define $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ by $T(v)=Av$, where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with entries from $\mathbb{R}$. But it seems so trivial though. Is there a way that I can explain this well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \dim\,\operatorname{Col}(A)$. Using this you should be able to determine the image of $T$.